# Dynamic DropDown in Angular2 is not populating the data

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am populating the dropdown based on the input value of previous dropdown, where i am populating the array whole in a once at a time and then on input value i am filtering the dynamic dropdown.

But once the filtering works as expected but on changing the dropdown input the dynamic data is not getting loaded again.

I am even using the change detector reference but no change is taking place.

Below is my code:

```
    @ViewChild('select1') select1: any; // reference variable for select

    getTheProductType(){
    var productTypeId = this.select1.value;
    this.productsAfterChangeEvent = this.allProducts.filter(p => p.typeId == productTypeId);
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <select #select1 (change)="getTheProductType()">
      <option *ngFor="let p of checkedOutProducts">{{p.name}}</option>
    </select>

    <select #select2>
       <option>Pick a product...</option>
       <option *ngFor="let p of productsAfterChangeEvent">{{p.name}}
       </option>
   </select>
```

How to do this in angular2.

I am not able to load the data if I change the value in select1 only first time i select the data in select1 dropdown i am getting the filtered data in second dropdown but when i again change the data no change is taking place.

Any help??

Any one has does this ever before ??

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are there errors in the console?

Comment: No errors. Its is working fine. on first time when i select an value from select1 dropdown, but subsequent change of value from select1 dropdown does not refrehes the data in second dropdown

Comment: do,console.log(this.productsAfterChangeEvent) and check if it has data?

Comment: yes i did that too. Its working fine and showing the correct data, but not refreshing

Comment: can you sned the console result?

Comment: Your best bet might be to create a simple https://jsfiddle.net/ demo so we can help you fiddle with it. I've managed to do what you want before, but did it quite differently with dropdown components wrapped inside custom components and using '@Input' and '@Output' variables to listen for changes, so you might want to look into that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the change event is not triggering because you don't have a value attribute set on your options?

You could try something like this (assuming p.typeId is unique):

```
<option *ngFor="let p of checkedOutProducts" [value]="p.typeId">{{p.name}}</option>
```

Comment: I have even given the value attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As i was using materializecss, it has initialization issue for dynamic data for select element. So if anyone is working with materializecss then need to add the attribute **[materializeSelectOptions]="dynamicDataArray"** for reinitialization of select element. Hope this helps anyone in future.